# Styling of external SVG file with symbols

Tags: svg

I have problem with styles in following example:

external svg file `file.svg`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <style>.cls-1{fill:#333;fill-rule:evenodd;}</style>
    </defs>
    <symbol id="1" viewBox="0 0 24 32">
        <title>2</title>
        <path class="cls-1" d="M50,66S38,52.63,38,46a12,12,0,0,1,24,0C62,52.63,50,66,50,66Zm0-16a4,4,0,1,1,4-4A4,4,0,0,1,50,50Z" transform="translate(-38 -34)"/>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

When I try to load it with below code, Chrome and Firefox do not respect `cls-1` class, it works on Opera fine though.

```
<svg width="100px"><use xlink:href="file.svg#1"></use></svg>
```

If you are wondering why I need that, I have bunch of svg icons and I combined them with gulp-svgstore into single svg.file, so I have many symbols in my real file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a bug, according to [SVG specs on `<use>` elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#UseElement), styles applied on a referenced element should come along the deep clone, in W3 words :

> For user agents that support Styling with CSS, the generated ‘g’
>   element carries along with it the "cascaded" property values on the
>   ‘use’ element which result from the CSS cascade [...].
>   Additionally, the copy (deep clone) of the referenced resource carries
>   along with it the "cascaded" property values resulting from the CSS
>   cascade on the original (i.e., referenced) elements. Thus, the result
>   of various CSS selectors in combination with the ‘class’ and ‘style’
>   attributes are, in effect, replaced by the functional equivalent of a
>   ‘style’ attribute in the generated content which conveys the
>   "cascaded" property values.

Mozilla's bugzilla does have [a report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=619632) from 2010 but nothing seems to have changed since.

I don't know which version of Opera you do use, but on v34.0 on osX, it doesn't work either.

---

Your best bet is to workaround this problem, by setting the styles of your symbols inline.

---

Note that in Firefox and Safari, if you do append your `<style>` element in the main document, then the class selector will work correctly, unfortunately, Blink (chrome+opera) doesn't do it well...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `all: inherit;` CSS property inside the external SVG, which will allow styles on the `use` element to cascade down into the SVG:
https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/07/16/styling-svg-use-content-css/